# Adding aditional fields to object dinamicaly

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have spring service that is returning user data as a `.json`

ArticleUserPublic.class

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;

@Data
public class ArticleUserPublic {
    private String username;
    private HashSet<Integer> favorites;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date created_at;
}
```

Data is return with this format:

```
{
      "username": "admin",
      "favorites": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      "created_at": "2021-03-17T13:44:10.206+00:00"
    }
```

How can I append additional 'message' field without modifying ArticleUserPublic class?
There are more classes like UserData, that I want to append this message or something else.

What I want to achieve:

```
{
      "message": "User exist!",
      "username": "admin",
      "favorites": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      "created_at": "2021-03-17T13:44:10.206+00:00"
    }
```

My current solution, maybe it can be done better, at the moment it adds objects in nested way, I want to change this to be in root level:

Custom message class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomMessage<Obejct>  {
    private String message;
    private boolean status;
    private HashMap<String, Obejct> data = new HashMap<>();

    public CustomMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void add(String key, Object t){
        this.data.put(key, (Obejct) t);
    }
```

How I add additional message as HashMap element:

```
    public CustomMessage<Object> getUser(Long userId) {
        var response = new CustomMessage<>();
        Optional<ArticleUser> user = userRepository.findById(userId);
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            response.setMessage("User found!");
            response.setStatus(true);

            ArticleUserPublic publishUser = new ArticleUserPublic();
            publishUser.setUsername(user.get().getUsername());
            publishUser.setFavorites(user.get().getFavorites());
            publishUser.setCreated_at(user.get().getCreated_at());
            response.add("data", publishUser);
        } else {
            response.setMessage("User not found");
            response.setStatus(false);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your class `ArticleUserPublic` and add the other fields. For example :

```java
@Data
public class ArticleWithMessage extends ArticleUserPublic {
  private String message;
  private String otherFields;

  ArticleWithMessage(ArticleUserPublic article){
    super(article);
  }

 ArticleWithMessage(){
  }

}
```

And then use it like this :

```java
public ArticleWithMessage getUser(Long userId) {
    Optional<ArticleUser> user = userRepository.findById(userId);
    if (user.isPresent()) {
        ArticleWithMessage fullUserArticle = new ArticleWithMessage(user.get());
        fullUserArticle.setMessage("User found!");
        fullUserArticle.setStatus(true);
        fullUserArticle.setUsername(user.get().getUsername());
        fullUserArticle.setFavorites(user.get().getFavorites());
        fullUserArticle.setCreated_at(user.get().getCreated_at());
        fullUserArticle.add("data", publishUser);
        return fullUserArticle;
    } else {
        ArticleWithMessage noUser = new ArticleWithMessage();
        noUser.setMessage("User not found");
        noUser.setStatus(false);
        return noUser;
    }

  return response;
}
```

Comment: Yes I thought about this, but I have many similar classes like `ArticleUserPublic`, and all of them I will need to extend. I was looking solution, when I can append element dynamically.

Comment: not sure : the data is coming from database or web service ?

Comment: data is coming from database, but I use custom classes to filter fields for http response